# grpc server streaming don't work when calling from client no reposne returned

Tags: grpc

i'm working on poc grpc application, try to read stream byte array from server (.net core application) , client is console application. i get empty stream response always.

i try to make both console apps and it's working fine . could any one advice plz what's wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhnOZ.png) this is the client call . it's never hit the highlighted line.

i'm expect to get the response stream.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.